# How to modify the content of a <th> from "Create By" to "Create Date"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a third party web application, and I have the following table:

[image]

Which shows `<th>` content to be equal to "`Created BY`", but I need to change the text to be "`Created`". So how can I do so using css? Now the `<th>` will not always be the third `<td>` inside the table, so I am searching for a selector which will mainly look for a content = "`Created BY`", ad not the 3rd `<th>`?

Can anyone advise on this please?

Comment: You can't evaluate "content" with CSS.

Comment: css is for styling. don't you mean `how to do that using JS`? as jquery is one of your tags..

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks if i can not achieve this using css , then there is no harm to use js ,, that why i use jquery tag also ..

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is to select the text element inside a th where there are:

- a shed text (no jQuery element only a pure DOM text node: nodeType == 3)
- a span element containing one span and two anchors

So, when selecting such an element (the shed text), you need to get the first childNodes, otherwise you risk to change the structure of the th element itself  if you change the whole text related to the th.

In order to select such a cell text you may use the index (nth-child or eq) or  the :contains selector.

Using pure js:

```
document.querySelectorAll('table thead tr th:nth-child(3)')[0].childNodes[0].textContent = 'Create Date';
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('table thead tr th:eq(2)').get(0).childNodes[0].textContent = 'Create Date';
```

or

```
$('table thead tr th:contains("Created By")').get(0).childNodes[0].textContent = 'Create Date';
```

The snippet:

```js
//
// wrap the code into the document ready event
//

$(function () {

//$('table thead tr th:eq(2)').get(0).childNodes[0].textContent = 'Create Date';
//$('table thead tr th:contains("Created By")').get(0).childNodes[0].textContent = 'Create Date';
document.querySelectorAll('table thead tr th:nth-child(3)')[0].childNodes[0].textContent = 'Create Date';


console.log(document.querySelectorAll('table thead tr th:nth-child(3)')[0].outerHTML)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="ct100_ct141_g_47394b7a_f5a8_47b9_a195_350ffe052f39_csr1_table" class="cbs-List">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="ms-vh-icon ms-minWidthHeader">1</th>
        <th class="ms-vh2">2</th>
        <th class="ms-vh2">Created By
            <span id="Created">
                <span class="sortarrow ms-sortarrowup-iconouter" style=""></span>
                <a id="CreatedASC" href="#" title="Ascending" onclick=""></a>
                <a id="CreatedDES" href="#" title="Descending" onclick=""></a>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th class="ms-vh2">4</th>
        <th class="ms-vh2">5</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: now i try the following "_<script>

$("th:contains('Create By')").each(function() {
alert(1);
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace('Create By', 'Create Date')
  )
});</script>_" at the end of the page,,, but it did not work also the alert(1) which i added did not fire.. BTW i am using jQuery 1.10.2

Comment: @gaetanoM, not so nice to copy the use of `html` from my answer after your original post was using the `text` function...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replace` function on the `html()` of the elements that contains the relevant text:

```js
$("th:contains('Create By')").each(function() {
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace('Create By', 'Create Date')
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Create By
      <div>some content</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: now i try the following "_<script>

$("th:contains('Create By')").each(function() {
alert(1);
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace('Create By', 'Create Date')
  )
});</script>_" at the end of the page,,, but it did not work also the alert(1) which i added did not fire.. BTW i am using jQuery 1.10.2

Comment: @johnG, You have different values in your title/image/question. `Created BY` vs `Create By`. You should stick with one :)

Comment: now i provided the following with BY capital :- "_ <script>

$("th:contains('Create BY')").each(function() {
alert(1);
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace('Create BY', 'Create Date')
  )
});
</script>
_" but i did not get any effect, and the alert will not fire ?

Comment: @johnG, Do you have any `Create BY` in your document? Create is **not** Create**d**. Your image contains Created

Comment: @johnG, did you check?

Comment: now i have more than one table inside the page,, but only one tables has one of its th contain "Created BY" text.

Comment: @johnG, I'm not sure if I understand if the answer is correct or you still have problems here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal way to solve the problem, but this answer is to prove jquery support this,

```
$("th:contains('Created BY')").each(function(){
     $(this).text('Created Date');
});
```